# How can I change the style of a Matplotlib plot, after it is created?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to toggle my plot between two different styles. But I'm having a problem finding out how to change the style after the plot is created.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("dark_background")  # create plot in dark format

fig, (axes1, axes2) = plt.subplots(2)

axes1.plot(range(5))
axes2.plot(range(4, -1, -1))

"""other code here"""

if True:  # condintion for changing style later
    plt.style.use("default")  # depending on code, change plot style back

plt.show()
```

If using the plt.style.use function doesn't work, is it possible using the rcParams?

Comment: No, one cannot change the style after the axes is created. In such case one would need to change each element individually using `.set_color()` and similar functions. Best use the [style in a context](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#temporary-styling), `with plt.style.context('dark_background'):`

Comment: Okay thanks, the context might be hard since I call different parts of the plot in different functions, but I think i'll just try doing it with the individual set_color functions. Thanks!